# Can't acces Html helper classes in intellisense on MVC4 newly added page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Hmm, so I am no MVC expert and I can't seem to find a difference here so I am stuck asking.

I added page to my MVC4 app (in VS11) called test (test.cshtml) and it works but I can't seem to get access to the Html classes in intellisense. If I type, for example @Html.BeginForm() it shows in Red underline like an error and when I type @Html. there is no intellisense. I can see it in the other pages (about.cshtml for example) - they use @html.Whatever() but I can't figure out how to tell my new page I want to use those classes? I am missing something.

I found this [Html Helper Not Working on nested Site Master page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989921/html-helper-not-working-on-nested-site-master-page) but that really isn't the same - this is MVC4 with Razor so I don't think you even have a code behind page?

I don't know - I hope I don't sound dumb, like I said. I am not really and MVC guy.

Comment: Where did you add the file? There's a `Views` folder that contains a `web.config` specific for Razor in there. (Just making sure)

Comment: Yeah, in the views - I recreated this project in 2010 and all is well. I think this is some weird issue with vs11.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with ASP.NET MVC 4 and Areas in Visual Studio 2012 (though perhaps just with QU1). Open the **Web.config** file located in the **Areas** directory, and replace instances of **__*Version*__.0.0** with **2.0.0.0** for **System.Web.WebPages.Razor**, and **4.0.0.0** for **System.Web.Mvc**.